# Same ajax call but changed data from same UI on multiple button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$("#myButton").click(function (e) {

    dataString = $("#myform").serialize();
    $("#ajaxResponse").empty();
    var $body = $('body');
    $body.addClass('loading');
    var html = '';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "hotelservlet",
        // data : { name : name, id : 'foo' },
        data: dataString,
        datatype: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $body.addClass('loading');
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
```

I have a web form which takes some input and get response on an AJAX call made on click of submit button and I also have two other buttons next and previous I want same AJAX call to be made on both the other buttons but with some changes made to the input.

I am using jQuery serialize method to make AJAX call. Please tell me how to change the inputs for ajax call of next and previous.

Comment: your question is not clear, what type of changes do you want to make?

Comment: ok i have date as an input like '2013-09-4' i want when next button is clicked the input date is been changed to '2013-09-5' and rest of the input remain the same and then ajax call is made.

Comment: can you add `cache:false` in you ajax code

Comment: how will that help me to again serialize my input form data with changed date using dataString = $("#myform").serialize(); method

Answer (score 0):

You can move the ajax call to a new method with input as the parameter. Then you can make differnt client click events for these three button. In the click event call the method for ajax call with corresponding parameter.

Comment: but @mahesh in my case i want one of my input to change automatically when next button is clicked i dont want the user to go and change to input

Comment: @SahilKohli are you using a datepicker plugin?

Comment: can you pls me how to use that datepicker plugin to change date